# traefik proxy - redirect to a site without proxying

Tags: traefik

Hi i would like my traefik proxy to redirect the user to a remote url without doing a proxy. Is this doable? I am using middlewares in my yaml

traefik.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.5
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.file=true"
      - "--providers.file.filename=/etc/traefik/rules.yml"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "8081:8081"
      - 80:80
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik_rules.yml:/etc/traefik/rules.yml
  whoami:
    # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    image: traefik/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.regex=http://localhost/(.*)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.replacement=https://www.google.com/$${1}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.permanent=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-route-2.middlewares=test-redirectregex@docker"
```

traefik-rules.yml

```
http:
  routers:
    my-route-2:
      rule: "Host(`localhost`)"
      service: my-keycloak-server-2
  services:
    my-keycloak-server-2:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "https://www.google.com"
```

i can see in my traefik dashboard the middleware "test-redirectregex" is created and attached to my service, but when i visit "http://localhost" it is not redirecting me - my browser url is still localhost and not google.com. Can this use case even be handled by Traefik Proxy? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

traefik-rules.yml

```
   http:
      routers:
        my-route:
          rule: "Host(`127.0.0.1`)"
          service: my-keycloak-server
        my-route-2:
          middlewares:
            - "test-redirectregex"
          rule: "Host(`localhost`)"
          service: my-keycloak-server-2
      services:
        my-keycloak-server:
          loadBalancer:
            servers:
              - url: "https://www.demo2.com"
        my-keycloak-server-2:
          loadBalancer:
            servers:
              - url: "https://www.demo.com"
      middlewares:
        test-redirectregex:
          redirectRegex:
            regex: "^http://localhost/(.*)"
            replacement: "https://www.demo2.com/${1}"
            permanent: true
```